# Angular 4+ - how to upload and display images?

Tags: angular, image-uploading

I'm not really clear on the options available here, if there are some.  Like many applications, I need to upload an image in Angular 4+ and then display it in the website.

Where are the images usually stored for Angular?  In a CDN or somehow locally in the assets folder of the Angular app?

There's no real good information about this anywhere, just lots of information about how to upload to Firebase.  Is that the only option for uploading images in Angular?

Keep in mind the upload feature is most likely part of admin protected component for the administrators.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a server side application that accepts file uploads. You can have the service place the images at a location of your choosing (local file system, CDN, etc).  The service should return the url of the image. Angular can use this service to upload the files (http request as blob) and assign the URLs that the service returns to the “src” attribute of img.